# Stata: How to reference subfolder after setting directory with cd

Tags: stata, cd

In SPSS, you can set a directory or path, like `cd 'C:\MyData'` and later refer to any subfolders within that directory, like `get file 'Subfolder1\Some file.sav'.`

How do you do this in Stata? Assume I have this folder structure:

```
C:\MyData\
    Subfolder1\
        data1.dta
        data2.dta
    Subfolder2\
        data3.dta
        data4.dta
```

Can I do:

```
cd "C:\MyData"
```

and then

```
use Subfolder1\data1.dta

    [a bunch of code ...]

use Subfolder2\data3.dta

    [a bunch of code]
```

I'm basically trying to avoid having to respecify the higher level folder I established with the initial `cd` command.

Comment: Remember you can always try out the code yourself and check the results.

Answer (score 3):

This is valid Stata syntax:

```
clear
set more off

cd "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/statatemps"
use "test/cauto.dta"
```

You could also do something like:

```
clear
set more off

local dirstub "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/statatemps"
use "`dirstub'/test/cauto.dta"
```

That is, define a directory stub using a `local`, and use it whenever needed. Unlike the first example, this form doesn't actually produce a directory change.

Comment: Thanks for both of these  options. The local one will come in very handy, as I can assign short names to several paths and easily use them where needed throughout the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the current directory, like this:

```
use "./Subfolder1/data1.dta"
```